# Can't install Packages with Cloned ArcGIS Pro Python

Tags: arcgis-pro, python-3, anaconda, conda

I have a new installation of ArcGIS Pro 2.6 on a Windows 10 computer.  I have successfully cloned Python because I want to install third-party packages to this cloned environment and still use arcpy.

I have added this new Python installation to the Path variables in Windows and I can confirm in a Windows command prompt that the newly cloned Anaconda Python is the default Python version.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to install third-party libraries.  For example, simplekml .  On a normal Python installation this would be easy with `pip install simplekml`command. Or in this case I would think `conda install simplekml`.
When I try `conda install simplekml` I get the following error.

How do I configure my computer to allow me to install third-party packages to this cloned Python version?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on Windows 10, search for "Python Command Prompt". This will open a window with the current default ArcGIS Pro python environment activated. Pip and other python modules should work normally, as well as conda.

Comment: Thanks, @Whiskers.  That worked  as described.