# Cannot install GeoPandas on cloned arcgispro env in Anaconda

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, geopandas, anaconda, environment-variable

I have cloned my `ArcGIS Pro env` into my `Anaconda 3 env`. My goal was to have access to both the `arcpy` mod and `GeoPandas` mod. I tested it in a notebook to make sure `arcpy` is working and it is. But `GeoPandas` is not in `>conda list.` I tried to install it both from the Anaconda Navigator package manager and using `>conda install geopandas`. Both returned the same error: `InvalidSpecError: Invalid spec: =2.7`. I've tried to use `pip` as well. In addition, I tried other solutions, including this [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379393/cant-install-packages-with-cloned-arcgis-pro-python) and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda) where I completely removed and tried to reinstall my `gdal` package and reinstall `geopandas` first. It failed and ruined the `gdal` package in the process. I have tried to clone my arcpgispro-py3 env to see if I can add it that way, but the clone attempt keeps failing. Is there any way to do this or is there some ESRI configuration that makes this impossible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geopandas is included with Python for ArcGIS Pro.  See the image below.  Maybe you have cloned your environment but your Python environment defaulted back to the walled garden version for some reason?

[image]